# Make Matplotlib date xtick labels more sparse (spread out) by every nth xtick label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a covid graph visualizer using matplotlib, however, on the x axis, I haven't been able to figure out how to split the date ranges into bigger intervals. For example, instead of having a tick for each month, have a tick for every 3 months. Here's a picture of my current graph and some code:

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
formatter = mdates.DateFormatter("%m/%d/%Y")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
plt.plot(dateX, confirmedY)
plt.show()
```

dateX is a list containing utc datetime timestamps/objects and confirmedY is a list of ints containing an equal amount of values representing the infections tally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the xticks to be every third day or what ever you input in `[0::3]`:

```
Import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-01-10')
y = np.random.randn(10)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(x[0::3])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, per your comment, let's say you want to include the last value.

```
Import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-01-12')
y = np.random.randn(12)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(x[0::3].append(x[-1:]))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I added:      

ax.set_xlim(dateX[0], dateX[len(dateX)-1])  and
plt.xticks(dateX[0::80])  

a bit better but i cant get the last date value to show up at the right corner of the graph (https://i.imgur.com/TIZS5Ky.png)